# How to pass row id by href link in mvc from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables, href, actionlink

I want to pass row Id from view to controller via href link from datatable in mvc.

Here is my **datatable** design code

```
<table id="dataGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here is the **datatable** action code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dataGrid").DataTable({
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "pageLength": 5,
        "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 50, 100, 1000, 10000],

        "columnDefs":
        [{
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false
        }
        ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
            { "data": "date", "name": "Date", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false, "format": "dd/MM/yyyy" },
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return " <a href='/ServiceJob/GetPrintById?'" + row.id + "'' class='btn btn-success btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-print'> Print </a> ";
                }
            },
        ]
    });
});
```

And here is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetPrintById(int id)
{
    ServiceJobModel model = new ServiceJobModel();

    // Service Job Detail
    var serviceJob = _Db.ServiceJob.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    model.Id = serviceJob.Id;
    model.Date = serviceJob.Date;

    return View("Print");
}
```

Now in datatable action code I tried in return by the following code

```
<a href='/ServiceJob/GetPrintById?'" + row.id + "'' class='btn btn-success btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-print'> Print </a>
```

but the above code is not working.

And in the place of **href** if I used the **actionlink** then at that time it showing the error i.e. **row does not exist in the current context**.

Here is the actionlink code,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print", "GetPrintById", "ServiceJob", new { id = row.id }, null)
```

So , for me both the code is not executing.

Help me to solve this issue.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `row` is a client-side variable and you can't use it inside `@Html.ActionLink()` helper which runs server-side. You can add row ID by using `@Url.Action()` helper and set the variable containing the complete URL into anchor tag's `href` attribute inside `render` setting:

```
"render": function (data, type, row) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetPrintById", "ServiceJob")/' + row.id; 

    return "<a href='" + url + "' class='btn btn-success btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-print'>Print</a> ";
}
```

**Update:**

Take note that anchor tag **always** uses GET request to call the path of controller action mentioned in `href` attribute, hence the `[HttpPost]` attribute on the controller action must be omitted/removed:

```
public IActionResult GetPrintById(int id)
{
    ServiceJobModel model = new ServiceJobModel();

    // Service Job Detail
    var serviceJob = _Db.ServiceJob.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    model.Id = serviceJob.Id;
    model.Date = serviceJob.Date;

    return View("Print");
}
```

Reference:

[Datatables with asp.net mvc rendering Url.actions/html.actionlinks with route values](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33255/datatables-with-asp-net-mvc-rendering-url-actions-html-actionlinks-with-route-values)

Comment: by doing this error is not coming but action is not fired in controller in **GetPrintById** method.

Comment: Anchor link always uses GET request, just remove `[HttpPost]` attribute and the controller action will fire.

Comment: awsome brother. And thankxxx a lot for the great information.